# How to change colors by steps

Tags: jquery, css, animation, colors, mouseover

I want to create a simple animation for my text on the mouseover : 
I want the text has the color : blue, then yellow, and then green.
All this by steps.

This code doesn't work for what I want to do :

**[DEMO IN MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/89qB6/)**

```
$('p').mouseover(function() {  
    $(this).css( 'color','blue' );  
    $(this).css( 'color','yellow' );  
    $(this).css( 'color','green' );  
    });

$('p').mouseout(function() {  
    $(this).css( 'color','' );  
    });
```

Comment: more information on this: do you want the text to change between those colors after an interval? each time you mouseenter change the color to the next one? carousel between those while mouseenter?

Comment: i mean seriously what to you expect to happen? on mouseover you change the color 3 times, ending with green...

Comment: Yes. All I want it's to : with once mouseover, we have a animation text color : blue firstly, then yellow, and green.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('p').each(function(i, item) {
   $(item).mouseover(function() {  
       $(this).css( 'color','blue' );  
       $(this).css( 'color','yellow' );  
       $(this).css( 'color','green' );  
    });
})

$('p').mouseout(function() {  
    $(this).css( 'color','' );  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hej there, its not possible to change css "color" with jquery animate without plugin :

> Is it possible to manipulate ALL CSS properties with the animate() method?
>
> Yes, almost! However, there is one important thing to remember: all property names must be camel-cased when used with the animate() >method: You will need to write paddingLeft instead of padding-left, marginRight instead of margin-right, and so on.
>
> Also, color animation is not included in the core jQuery library.
>   If you want to animate color, you need to download the Color Animations plugin from jQuery.com.

But you can try it with css3 transitions :

```
p:hover {
    color:blue;
    transition-property:color;
    transition-duration: 2s, 2s;
}
```

just add this to your css and hover over it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid css3 transitions, you can use jQuery UI's animate functionality.

It would like something like this...

```
$('p').mouseover(function() {  

    var textToAnimate = $(this);    

    textToAnimate.animate({'color': 'blue'}, 500, function(){        
        textToAnimate.animate({'color': 'yellow'}, 500, function(){            
            textToAnimate.animate({'color': 'green'}, 500);            
        });        
    });
});

$('p').mouseout(function() {  
    $(this).css( 'color','' );  
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/89qB6/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
$('p').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'blue').delay(1000)
            .queue(function() {
                $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
                $(this).dequeue();
            }).delay(1000) 
    .queue(function() {
                $(this).css('color', 'green');
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
});

$('p').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css('color', '');
});
```

Change the delay as you want.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/89qB6/7/)